# Why GitHub shows someone else commit to my repository but it was done by myself?

Tags: git

I committed as usual to my remote [repository](https://github.com/ComplicatedPhenomenon/Fortran_practice) on GitHub, but recently I found after my committing, it shows that was being done by another people. It is weird and I don't know why.

Comment: check `git config user.name` in your local system

Comment: Yes, it's not my name, It must have changed automatically. I don't know how it became so. I have cloned some repository of that users' repository

Comment: so change it using `git config --global user.name <yourUserName>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Identity**

The first thing you should do when you install Git is to set your user name and email address. This is important because every Git commit uses this information, and it’s immutably baked into the commits you start creating:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"

$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Again, you need to do this only once if you pass the `--global` option, because then Git will always use that information for anything you do on that system. If you want to override this with a different name or email address for specific projects, you can run the command without the `--global` option when you’re in that project.